# Vuetify 2. Прикрепление меню к v-select

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, прокрутка, vuetify

Столкнулся с необычной ситуацией. Основная цель - прикрепить меню и отобразить, либо выше, либо ниже данного селекта (в зависимости от того, хватит ему места для отображения или нет). В целом,после того, как я прошерстил всю доку,понял след:

1. Чтобы отобразить меню либо выше, либо ниже селекта стоит добавить свойства overflow-y, overflow-offset в menu-props.
2. Поставить в v-select attach, чтобы menu прикрепилось к селекту, и при скроле не шаталось по всему экрану)

Однако, overflowOffset прекратил свою работу. Как быть и убить сразу двух зайцев?